# What organelles are in an onion cell?

Tags: cell-biology, plant-physiology, eukaryotic-cells

I was wondering what organelles are in an onion cell, because, based on the labs we are doing in my biology class, I only saw a nucleus and cell wall. My friends and brother say there are all the organelles that you would find in a typical plant cell, but I can't find any evidence anywhere. I need to create a model and it's due in a week.

Comment: what magnifivation was used to see it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so the first thing you always do when recreating a cell microscope slide (like drawing or modelling the cell) is that you only **draw or model what you see**. In your case, this would just be the nucleus, the cell membrane and the cell wall.

To answer your question, onion cells (you usually use epithelial cells for this experiment) are ‘normal’ cells with all of the ‘normal’ organelles: nucleus, cytoplasm, cell wall and membrane, mitochondria, ribosomes, rough and smooth endoplasmic reticulum, centrioles, Golgi body and vacuoles. You cannot see most of these as they appear translucent as well as being too small to see under the light microscope. You need an electron microscope to view these. Note: chloroplasts are **not** present in an onion cell as it is not a photosynthesising cell.

This is a typical onion cell slide with labels:

[image: This is a typical onion cell slide with labels]